# MLX90621 no Acknowlegde with the RAM

Tags: embedded, stm32, sensors, i2c

First off all I am a beginner regarding embedded programming.

For an application I do want to use the MLX90621 thermo pixel array togehter with an STM32G431KB. On the Melexis Website is an example Code with some sort off abstraction. I moddified the lowlevel part of the code to work with the HAL library of the MCU.

For some reason I can read the EEPROM and write to it, get an acknowledge... But when trying to read from the adress 0x60, the RAM, where the sensorvalues are stored i do not get an acknowledge. I do have checkt with an logic analyer and I am sending the correct messages. Just for refference I do have added the code part of the read function.

Has anybody an idea regarding some very dump timing error or something like that.

P.S. Allready tried an different sensor of my order with the exact same result.

```c
int MLX90621_I2CRead(uint8_t slaveAddr,uint8_t command, uint8_t startAddress, uint8_t addressStep, uint8_t nMemAddressRead, uint16_t *data)
{
  uint8_t sa = slaveAddr << 1;                                                        
  int cnt = 0;
  int i = 0;
  uint8_t cmd[4] = {0,0,0,0};
  uint8_t i2cData[132] = {0};
  uint16_t *p;

  p = data;
  cmd[0] = command;
  cmd[1] = startAddress;
  cmd[2] = addressStep;
  cmd[3] = nMemAddressRead;

  if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, sa, cmd, 4, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK) 
    return -1;
         
    HAL_Delay(1);
  //sa = sa | 0x01;
  //ack = i2c.read(sa, i2cData, 2*nMemAddressRead, 0);
  if (HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c2, sa, i2cData, 2*nMemAddressRead, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
    return -1; 

  for (cnt = 0; cnt < nMemAddressRead; cnt++) {
    i = cnt << 1;
    *p++ = (uint16_t)i2cData[i+1]*256 + (uint16_t)i2cData[i];
  }

  return 0;   
}
```